# Падают тесты после добавления Flask-Breadcrumbs

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-3.6, breadcrumbs

Собственно, суть проблемы в заголовке. До установки и использования Flask-Breadcrumbs все было прекрасно. Сейчас при попытке прогнать тесты через Tox, падает KeyError в Flask-Menu.

```
    @staticmethod
    def root():
        """Return a root entry of current application's menu."""
>       return current_app.extensions['menu']
E       KeyError: 'menu'

.tox/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_menu/__init__.py:66: KeyError
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился. Всегда подключайте все расширения в app-fabric, не повторяйте моих ошибок.